# grep up to and including equal sign for CLI parameter

Tags: bash, grep

My goal is to match a command line argument prefix that looks like:

```
--abc=
```

Both of the patterns below (and many others), allow:

```
--abc==
```

Somehow, I can't find a grep way to ensure there is just one equal sign.

```
grep -i '^--[a-z]\{2,\}=\{1,1\}'
grep -i '^--[a-z]\{2,\}='
```

grep 2.20
CentOS Linux 7.3.1611

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Please provide some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ERE:

```
^--[[:alpha:]]{2,}=[^=]+$
```

- `^--[[:alpha:]]{2,}=` matches `--`, then two or more alphabetic characters in your `locale`, then a literal `=`
- `[^=]+$` matches one or more characters that are not `=` at the end

---

BRE:

```
^--[[:alpha:]]\{2,\}=[^=]\+$
```

---

**Example:**

```
$ grep -E '^--[[:alpha:]]{2,}=[^=]*$' <<<'--foobar=spam'
--foobar=spam

$ grep -E '^--[[:alpha:]]{2,}=[^=]*$' <<<'--foobar=23'
--foobar=23

$ grep -E '^--[[:alpha:]]{2,}=[^=]*$' <<<'--123ad='

$ grep -E '^--[[:alpha:]]{2,}=[^=]+$' <<<'--spamegg='
```

Comment: tks! The E style is much cleaner & looks much more like Java/PHP regex so it's my new default :) The grep std regex must be an ancient holdover from *nix' early days.

Comment: @iletras BRE is there for portability among all *nix systems.